# Looking to drive an ST-Link in standalone mode

Tags: firmware

At present I have one connected to interface the IAR EWARM s/w running on a PC. Does anyone do a standalone program just to take an output file and burn it to flash? [I'm using STM32F303x MCU]

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question correctly, but I think what you are looking for is something like the [ST-Link Utiliy](http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/tools/PF258168). Or do you mean something not running on a PC?

Comment: At present I connect through the IAR IWARM IDE. This is obviously not very practical for production. So I need something to replaced the licensed IAR s/w but which will use the IAR output file

Comment: Just use the above utility. You will need an ST-Link, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ST-Link utility](http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/tools/PF258168) can be used to program a given file.

It supports S-Record, Bin, Hex and S19 files. You have to create one of those out of your `.out`-File using the IELFTOOL at the end of your build-process (can be automated, so your hex-file never goes out of sync).

The ST-Link utility has also a command line interface, so it can be integrated in automatic production programming.

It supports verification of the downloaded firmware, so you can set those options and it will check if the firmware was downloaded correctly, which is a nice feature to have in production.

The various return values for different errors allow for different actions to be taken automatically.